# Access IIS cache from Console

Tags: c#, caching

Is it possible for a c# console application to create a cache object that would be accessible by an asp.net page?

Ie: The console application creates a cache object the asp.net just reads it whenever needed it.

Thank you

Comment: Yes. Seems nasty to me though, and will almost certainly create more problems than it solves.. What problem are you hoping this will solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box, because your console application and your asp.net application run in 2 separate processes. So you have to choose a way for them to communicate. And to do that you need 2 things: 1 that your objects are serialized in a certain way, and 2 that your process communicate through some form of protocol.

So this is going to require way more work that can be expressed in a StackOverflow answer.

But instead of reinventing the wheel, you might as well use a .net object database to do that.